# Existing WiFi connections need restart to work

Tags: 8.1, wifi

I currently have a Nokia Lumia 930.

The major annoyance at the moment is that at times it just wouldn't connect to any existing network unless restarted. Turning WiFi off and back on doesn't solve the issue, only a restart does.

I've observed this behaviour on various routers/hotspots..

Is there a better solution? An internet search didn't turn up anything directly related.

Comment: Have you tried turning WiFi sense ON / OFF?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the connection and reading the connection. In many cases the required security certificates may not be up to date on your phone. Also make sure that the check box for connect automatically is checked. If these are already done does the issue still happen? Is your phone at the most updated version of Windows Phone? What version are you using?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Christian on my 930 that like him, happens from time to time. Removing the connection doesn't help. The automatic connect checkbox is checked. I am using the lastest version of Windows Phone 8.10.14234.375. Only a restart works for me as well.

Comment: @JukEboX This also happens for "open" (non-secure) hotspots. I'm using the latest stable WP 8.1 version.

Comment: Does it say "can't do this right now" or does it show the actual networks you can see?

Comment: It shows networks..

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not so much with the phone but the wifi itself,

i have it and after much testing (im pro QA) i must come up with a conclusion that certain wifi setups cause this issue to come about, as i didnt have access to settings of the networks which caused the problem, couldnt figure out what exactly is it (though all networks were security-keen).

Since no android had same problem (but all WP i tried did), it must be due to WP not supporting some of the security features which cause wifi crash, if you can play with settings, in my case there was nothing i could do.

Comment: As I already mentioned, this problem happened to me very often on open(non-secure) networks...

Comment: where do you see problem? it mustnt be security (though in my case it was most likely), just a general but specific setting in wifi's which microsoft team has not addressed yet. BTW the win10 preview son my lumia 735 seems to handle those issues fine and no wifi lockup so far